# Cannot update git repository: "sign_and_send_pubkey: no mutual signature supported"

Tags: git, ssh

I'm working with a git repository, connecting with it by using a ssh key.

It worked fine until today. I was performing a pull and I've obtained the following ssh error:

```
sign_and_send_pubkey: no mutual signature supported
```

And then it asks for a password for the `git` user of the server (that I don't have).

It's strange because it always worked before. This is the output with the diagnostic log of ssh:

```
$ GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvvv" git pull origin Develop
OpenSSH_8.8p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1m  14 Dec 2021
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname SERVER.IP.ADDRESS is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/c/Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/c/Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to SERVER.IP.ADDRESS [SERVER.IP.ADDRESS] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 4 IP_TOS 0x48
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.4 pat OpenSSH_5* compat 0x0c000002
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to SERVER.IP.ADDRESS:22 as 'git'
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from SERVER.IP.ADDRESS
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: umac-64@openssh.com compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from SERVER.IP.ADDRESS
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host 'SERVER.IP.ADDRESS' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug1: Will attempt key: /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_xmss
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa':
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
sign_and_send_pubkey: no mutual signature supported
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_xmss
debug3: no such identity: /c/Users/myuser/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@SERVER.IP.ADDRESS's password:
```

What I'm doing wrong?

I'm using git for windows (tried both git bash and powershell consoles), version 2.35.3.windows.1.

Comment: See https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/ssh-rsa-key-rejected-with-message-no-mutual-signature-algorithm-1026057701.html

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I got this error at openstack and the solution for me was:

```
ssh -o 'PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa' -i id_microstack cirros@10.20.20.15
```

Answer (score 18):

The error means the server and client couldn't find an algorithm that both support. Probably, the server is too old and only supports deprecated algorithms that your client doesn't accept anymore. Or, your client key is signed with an old algorithm.

The solution depends on the situation: You might need to upgrade the server, the client, or re-generate your key with a newer algorithm.

But if you want to re-enable old algorithms again, you can do it by adding the following to your `~/.ssh/config` file. (If the file doesn't exist, create it).

```
Host alias my-host.co
  PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-rsa
```

Notes:

- These old algorithms are deprecated because they are no longer considered secure. So this should be your last solution.
- I only enabled the old algorithms for a single host, to reduce the risk.
- I enabled `ssh-rsa`. You might need some others, like `ssh-dss`.

Answer (score 8):

add in file ~/.ssh/config (nano ~/.ssh/config)

```
Host *
PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes=+ssh-dss
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).